# Trying to run unit test and get this message Use of undeclared identifier 'QRCLocalizedLabels' using XCode 10 Beta 4 and iOS 12 Beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, ios12

Trying to run unit test and get this message Use of undeclared identifier 'QRCLocalizedLabels' using XCode 10 Beta 4 and iOS 12 Beta 6

I can't find why I am getting this errors.

[image]

[image]

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface QRCLocalizedLabels : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *supportedLanguages;


+(QRCLocalizedLabels*) getInstance;
-(NSString*) localizedValueForKey:(NSString*)key;
-(void)refreshInstance;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the latest xCode 10 Beta version. Beta 5 is already out. Some errors are corrected in the new beta version.